# Update statement PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Well I'm writing a procedure where I have an execute immediate in it. This is my code.

```
  PROCEDURE upd_row(
  table_name VARCHAR2,
  set_values VARCHAR2,
  conditions VARCHAR2 := NULL)IS 
  BEGIN 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '|| table_name || 'SET' || set_values|| ' WHERE ' || conditions ||')';
  END;
```

As you can see I have 3 parameters. This is the code how I call it.

```
table_pkg.upd_row('my_contacts','name=''Nancy Greenberg''','id=2');
```

The erorr I am getting is: 'missing SET keyword'

Answer (score 1):

The error is when you concatenate the `SET` keyword to the `set_values` and `table_name`, you don't leave a space in between, so this concatenates all of this words together.

So you code should look like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '|| table_name || ' SET ' || set_values|| ' WHERE ' || conditions ;
```

Btw, consider deleting the `')'` at the end of the execute immediate, cause it will make the statement fail because there is not any opening `(`.

Comment: Now I get this error: 00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"

Comment: Without seeing all of the code its actually hard to know which object already exists, but my guess will be that the name of the procedure upd_row that you're creating already exists, try create or replace when creating the procedure if you want to update or create it.